# Can't fix npm audit vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lodash

I have a react js electron repo, where when I run `npm i` in my windows 10 command prompt, I get this output:

```
34 vulnerabilities (1 low, 9 moderate, 16 high, 8 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

I want to fix all the vulnerabilities, so will start with the 8 critical issues.
I've tried running `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` but the number of vulnerabilities is the same.

I installed the npm package `npm-check-updates` to make sure everything in my package.json file was up to date:

```
npx npm-check-updates
Checking C:\Users\marti\repo\package.json
[====================] 27/27 100%

All dependencies match the latest package versions :)
```

But when I run `npm audit`, even after deleting my node_modules and package-lock.json before running `npm i` again, I still see it says 8 critical vulnerabilities.

So I run npm audit and pick one of the critical vulnerabilities to try and fix:

```
lodash.merge  <=4.6.1
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in lodash.merge - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-2m96-9w4j-wgv7
Prototype Pollution in lodash.merge - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-h726-x36v-rx45
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-jf85-cpcp-j695
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/multispinner/node_modules/lodash.merge
  multispinner  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash.merge
  node_modules/multispinner
```

I added `"lodash": "^4.17.21"` to my package.json dependencies (it wasnt there before) and deleted package-lock.json / node_modules, ran `npm i`  again, but there are still 8 critical vulnerabilities including the lodash one.

Do the `npm audit fix` commands not work in command prompt? I'm using node version `v14.18.1`

Comment: The `multispinner` package uses a vulnerable version lodash (https://github.com/codekirei/node-multispinner/blob/master/package.json). So, until that package is not updated, you won't be able to get rid of this vulnerability.

Comment: @PrerakSola I don't have the `multispinner` package or string anywhere within my package.json, but i do see it appears in my package-lock.json under `"node_modules/electron-scripts": { "version": "1.1.3", "dependencies": {` , so i think its getting downloaded because of electron-scripts

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-scripts?activeTab=dependencies